# Adding Row using Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, html-table

I was trying to create a program to add rows dynamically using Javascript in HTML Table using the Add Row Button. There seems to be an error.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home - First Website</title>
    <style>
    table{
        width: 100%;
    }
    td{
        padding: 8px;
        border: 1px solid;
    }
    input[type="text"]{
        width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function add(){
        var num=parseInt(document.getElementById("t1").length+1);
        var a=document.createElement("td");
        var anode=document.createTextNode(num);
        a.appendChild(anode);
        document.getElementById("t1").appendChild(a);

        a=document.createElement("td");
        anode=document.createElement("input");
        var b=document.createAttribute("type");
        b.value="checkbox";
        anode.setAttributeNode(b);
        a.appendChild(anode);
        document.getElementById("t1").appendChild(a);

        a=document.createElement("td");
        anode=document.createElement("input");
        b=document.createAttribute("type");
        b.value="text";
        anode.setAttributeNode(b);
        a.appendChild(anode);
        document.getElementById("t1").appendChild(a);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table name="t1">
        <tr>
            <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="add()">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1.</td><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="text" style="width:100%;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `parseInt` on something that's already an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code :

1) for adding row why are you doing this :

```
var num=parseInt(document.getElementById("t1").length+1);
```

: please note you haven't  given your table any id.

I think you need count to number your rows. You can get that by :

```
var num =document.getElementById("t1").rows.length;
```

2) For adding a row, you have not created `<tr>` element!

Here's the corrected jsFiddle : 
**http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/kCm2D/1/**

**update** : changed the way to get number of rows.

**js**

```
function add() {
     var num = var num =document.getElementById("t1").rows.length;
     console.log(num);
     var x = document.createElement("tr");

     var a = document.createElement("td");
     var anode = document.createTextNode(num);
     a.appendChild(anode);
     x.appendChild(a);

     a = document.createElement("td");
     anode = document.createElement("input");
     var b = document.createAttribute("type");
     b.value = "checkbox";
     anode.setAttributeNode(b);
     a.appendChild(anode);
     x.appendChild(a);

     a = document.createElement("td");
     anode = document.createElement("input");
     b = document.createAttribute("type");
     b.value = "text";
     anode.setAttributeNode(b);
     a.appendChild(anode);
     x.appendChild(a);
     document.getElementById("t1").appendChild(x);
 }
```

**html**

```
<table id="t1" name="t1"> <!-- "t1" is id as well -->
    <tr>
        <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="add()" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" style="width:100%;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `getElementById` but your table has a name not an id.

```
 <table name="t1">
```

to

```
<table id="t1">
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is on document.getElementById("t1"), but your table doesn't have an id="t1", it has a name="ti".
Update to this:

```
<table id="t1">
```